# Looking for Nodejs HTML reporter for automated tests running on Jenins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, automated-tests, mocha.js, supertest

We run our automated API acceptance tests on Jenkins. They were written in ruby and we're moving them to NodeJS. I'm looking for an HTML reporter plugin for Jenkins that produces reports similar to the nice HTML reports produced by https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin, specifically, the feature report and feature statistics. Anybody know of an HTML reporter that would work for mocha/chai/supertest (which is what we're moving to)? I've tried mocha-junit-reporter but as far as I know it only produces summary results like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at "doc" and "html" reporter. Both are explained [here](https://mochajs.org/) . Also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974122/using-html-reporting-with-mocha-test-framework) post

Comment: you can also use third party reporters. For more info look [here](https://github.com/travisjeffery/mocha-teamcity-reporter) and [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments folks. I think I found what I was looking for. There's a mocha HTML reporter called mochawesome that is apparently runnable on Jenkins.